# installing OpenVZ on CentOS 6

Tags: centos, kernel, openvz

Im trying to install OpenVZ on CentOS 6.
I used this instruction to install OpenVZ :
https://www.unixmen.com/install-and-configure-openvz-on-centos/

I tried to update the kernel, modify the openvz repo, nothing helped.
here is the problem :

```
[root@CentOS-69-64-minimal ~]# yum install vzkernel
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Setting up Install Process
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.fra10.de.leaseweb.net
 * extras: mirror.fra10.de.leaseweb.net
 * openvz-kernel-rhel6: mirror.netinch.com
 * openvz-utils: mirror.netinch.com
 * updates: mirror.fra10.de.leaseweb.net
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package vzkernel.x86_64 0:2.6.32-042stab131.1 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: kernel-firmware >= 2.6.32-754.el6 for package: vzkernel-2.6.32-042stab131.1.x86_64
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: vzkernel-2.6.32-042stab131.1.x86_64 (openvz-kernel-rhel6)
           Requires: kernel-firmware >= 2.6.32-754.el6
           Installed: kernel-firmware-2.6.32-696.30.1.el6.noarch (@updates)
               kernel-firmware = 2.6.32-696.30.1.el6
           Available: kernel-firmware-2.6.32-696.el6.noarch (base)
               kernel-firmware = 2.6.32-696.el6
           Available: kernel-firmware-2.6.32-696.1.1.el6.noarch (updates)
               kernel-firmware = 2.6.32-696.1.1.el6
           Available: kernel-firmware-2.6.32-696.3.1.el6.noarch (updates)
               kernel-firmware = 2.6.32-696.3.1.el6
           Available: kernel-firmware-2.6.32-696.3.2.el6.noarch (updates)
               kernel-firmware = 2.6.32-696.3.2.el6
           Available: kernel-firmware-2.6.32-696.6.3.el6.noarch (updates)
               kernel-firmware = 2.6.32-696.6.3.el6
           Available: kernel-firmware-2.6.32-696.10.1.el6.noarch (updates)
               kernel-firmware = 2.6.32-696.10.1.el6
           Available: kernel-firmware-2.6.32-696.10.2.el6.noarch (updates)
               kernel-firmware = 2.6.32-696.10.2.el6
           Available: kernel-firmware-2.6.32-696.10.3.el6.noarch (updates)
               kernel-firmware = 2.6.32-696.10.3.el6
           Available: kernel-firmware-2.6.32-696.13.2.el6.noarch (updates)
               kernel-firmware = 2.6.32-696.13.2.el6
           Available: kernel-firmware-2.6.32-696.16.1.el6.noarch (updates)
               kernel-firmware = 2.6.32-696.16.1.el6
           Available: kernel-firmware-2.6.32-696.18.7.el6.noarch (updates)
               kernel-firmware = 2.6.32-696.18.7.el6
           Available: kernel-firmware-2.6.32-696.20.1.el6.noarch (updates)
               kernel-firmware = 2.6.32-696.20.1.el6
           Available: kernel-firmware-2.6.32-696.23.1.el6.noarch (updates)
               kernel-firmware = 2.6.32-696.23.1.el6
           Available: kernel-firmware-2.6.32-696.28.1.el6.noarch (updates)
               kernel-firmware = 2.6.32-696.28.1.el6
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
[root@CentOS-69-64-minimal ~]#
```

also, I could not find any way to install openvz on centos 7, or debian 9, or ubuntu.
looks that OpenVZ is going to die. and its so bad, cause of I use it alot.

Comment: Facing the same problem right now, do you have any progress in finding solutions?

Answer (score 0):

> Currently I have vzkernel installed after the same problem.

The problem is that new version requires kernel of CentOS 7+, which is not available for CentOS 6.9
So I managed to download old version of vzkernel package and install it using RPM.

1. **Download latest compatible RPM**

   wget http://download.openvz.org/kernel/branches/rhel6-2.6.32/042stab126.2/vzkernel-2.6.32-042stab126.2.x86_64.rpm
2. **Install it**

   rpm -ivh vzkernel-2.6.32-042stab126.2.x86_64.rpm
3. **Check it**

   rpm -qa vzkernel
4. **Profit.**

Answer (score 0):

You can find `kernel-firmware >= 2.6.32-754.el6` in `[centosplus]` repo. Just enable it in your repo file in `/etc/yum.repos.d/` like:

```
[centosplus] 
name=CentOS-$releasever - Plus 
mirrorlist=http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=$releasever&arch=$basearch&repo=centosplus 
#baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/$releasever/centosplus/$basearch/ 
gpgcheck=1 
enabled=1 
gpgkey=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-6
```